# Nginx 403 forbidden

Tags: nginx

When I try to get a picture from a folder like http://server/icon.jpeg it gives an error 403 forbidden. what is the problem if the folder has user access www-data ?
This is my code:

```
  server {
       location /{
         proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
       }
       location ~ \.(gif|jpeg|png)$ {
          root /root/ShopsAggregator/usersicons;
           autoindex on;
            autoindex_exact_size off;
       }
  }
```

Comment: Does the file `/root/ShopsAggregator/usersicons/icon.jpeg` exist? What is the entry in the access and error logs? Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration that Nginx is reading and ensure that there are no other `server` blocks.

Comment: server {
    listen        80;
    server_name   example.com *.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

I have this server configuration and my

Comment: Edit your question to add additional information. The comments section is not suitable.